# Check if Videofile isn't corrupt or fake

Tags: c#, video, corruption

Is there a way to check if a Videofile is playable (by the WMP i.e.)? I mean a way to check if a File isn't corrupt or just a file with a fake ending, that it actually contains footage? Does somone know a Library that can do somthing like this? I'm not looking for a sepcific Videofile type, just as many as possible. I'm not looking for a way to check if a file is a Videofile, but if its actually playable.

Comment: To some reasonable extent, checking for playability might be opening the file with *your favotite* tool or library and checking if you care get duration and it appears to be non-zero.

Comment: There are other answers that may be useful in your case
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894903/how-can-i-validate-a-video-file-from-a-script
or
http://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4

Comment: OK, thx I'm using ffmpeg now and i works fine

Answer (score 1):

This question can not be answered because there is no such thing as playable. You need to define playable. What should happen if the video file is 50% playable? 90%? 1%? What do you if there is a missing frame (it will play to the end, but there will be some visual artifacts) that playable? is a JPEG 'playable' as a single frame?